# How to get hibernate button in unity shutdown dialog in Ubuntu Raring 13.04?

Tags: unity, 13.04, hibernate, usability

I checked that hibernation works on my laptop via pm-hibernate command, and then enabled hibernation. The unity panel menu shows an option for hibernation now, and it works fine.

My question here is, how to add it to the unity shutdown dialog. Since 13.04, unity has a new shutdown prompt when we press the power button, and it does not contain hibernate option even after enabling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hibernate icon appears only after a reboot. I am getting a hibernate icon now properly.